# scrollIntoView angular application

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am working on an Angular single page application. I have a navbar. I am using fragments to jump to section and anchorScrolling is enabled.

How should I scroll to a specific section when refreshing the page and when the URL contains the hash fragments? `xx/#sectionToJUmp`.

I have tried `scrollIntoView`, in the `ngAfterViewINit()`, but it's not working. The specific section is in a position, but it goes down when other sections are loaded. The scroll remains in the before position. How to get it in the specific section position? Thank you